# How to read a TypeScript signature with multiple arrows and generics?

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, method-signature

I am trying to understand this TypeScript signature from `react-hook-forms`:

```
handleSubmit: <TSubmitFieldValues extends FieldValues = TFieldValues>(onValid: SubmitHandler<TSubmitFieldValues>, onInvalid?: SubmitErrorHandler<TFieldValues>) => (e?: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) => Promise<void>;
```

Especially, but not only I want to understand:

1. What does the equals sign in the generic type mean?

   `<TSubmitFieldValues extends FieldValues = TFieldValues>`
2. How can there be two arrows in the signature?

   `[removed for shortening] => (e?: React.BaseSyntheticEvent) => Promise<void>`

Would be great if someone could explain the signature step-by-step, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does the equals sign in the generic type mean?

It's the default type.

> How can there be two arrows in the signature?

It's a function that returns another function. For example, this function:

```
const myWeirdAdd = arg1 => arg2 => arg1+arg2;
```

Can we called this way:

```
myWeirdAdd(1)(2); // returns 3;
```

And it's type would be:

```
type CurriedAdd = (arg1: number) => (arg2: number) => number;
```